# How to read file with é in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am using node.js with reading file and writing another file with some modification.

I am facing problem. When i read the file, i got the below issue

```
 détente - This word is converted to d�tente
```

I am using the following code.

```
 var filevalue=fs.readFileSync("file1.xml",'utf8').toString();
```

The value is wrongly converted.

Please assist me.

Note: I got answer the above issue: Thanks for reference

```
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-xml
```

Comment: You should use the proper encoding. Judging by the output, it is not using `utf-8` encoding.

Comment: The file just happens to not be encoded as utf8. Find out what encoding it is in then use the correct encoding when reading.